# How to add app to all pages in django?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-views

I have an app called lastapp that I would like it to be viewable on all pages. It renders base.html so it's available on all apps. So far I've tried adding it to the urls.py like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^first/$', firstapp, lastapp),
    (r'^last/$', lastapp),
)
```

But when I go to /first/ it gives me the error: Error, 'function' not iterable. It shows fine when going to /last/. If I remove lastapp from the /first/ site in urls.py, then firstapp shows fine also. Is there a special way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

All installed applications are available in your project, but the application by it self does not return any data to the template, that's the job of the views which are part of that application.

My guess is that `firstapp` and `lastapp` are rather views then apps.

If that is a case, [context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) make it possible to always pass certain data to a template.

So, create a context processor out of `lastapp` and set it in [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) in settings.py.

Comment: Yes, both lastapp and firstapp are views. All lastapp does is fetch data from a model in firstapp. Thanks for pointing out context processors.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is probably [Middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/).